# Discriminated union of recursive type

Tags: c++, c++11, unions

I read about discriminated unions in C++ here: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#unions

What if I wanted to make a union of recursive types?

For example, consider the following:

```
class Obj {
  enum class Type { kInt, kVec } type;
  union {
    int i;
    std::vector<Obj> v;
  };
  Obj& operator=(const Obj& o) { ... }
};
```

In this case the compiler complains about trying to use incomplete object `Obj` due to the recursive reference. How to work around this in a clean way?

Thanks

Comment: There is a school of thought saying you should avoid / don't actually need unions in modern C++.

Comment: In C++, use `std::variant`

Comment: @Ron I didn't know, thanks. Could you provide some references to the arguments of this school and what the alternative should be? In the context of this question, I'm still curious to know how to use the union properly though.

Comment: @ale64bit Plenty of references here on SO.

Comment: @liliscent I'm aware of `variant` but that's c++17 only. I want to know how it works without having to swim in `variant`'s sources.

Comment: Unions [with non-POD types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) are nasty. For example, `v` needs its constructor and destructor called and you have to take extra steps to see to it that this is done. I'll see if I can find a link.

Comment: Which compiler do you use, it compiles with all compiler I tested.

Comment: @Oliv I'm using clang 5.0. Can you share the code that works for you, since I omitted the overload of =? (example here: https://ideone.com/fOg0gY)

Comment: So I give you your answer and then vote to close, for the reason I cited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem of type recursivity here: `vector` internal state has only members of pointer to valute_type.

I think that if you had tried to follow the stackoverflow rule "[How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you would have certainly find yourself the answer.

In the example code you provide in the comment, there are many errors that the compiler complains about: The copy constructor of Obj is deleted so is the destructor, then the assigment operator is private etc...

I just fixed the error one by one and get the right code example which is the answer you could have found:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Obj {
  enum class Type { kInt, kVec } type;
  union {
    int i;
    vector<Obj> v;
  };
  public:
  Obj(const Obj& o):type{o.type}{
      if (o.type==Type::kVec)
          new (&v) vector<Obj>(o.v);
      else
          i=o.i;
  }
  Obj(Obj&& o):type{o.type}{
      if (o.type==Type::kVec)
          new (&v) vector<Obj>(std::move(o.v));
      else
         i=o.i;
  }
  ~Obj(){ if (type==Type::kVec) v.~vector<Obj>();}
  Obj& operator=(const Obj&o){
      if (o.type==Type::kVec && type==Type::kVec){
        v=o.v;
        return *this;
      }
      if (type == Type::kVec) {
      v.~vector();
    }
    switch (o.type) {
    case Type::kInt:
      i = o.i;
      break;
    case Type::kVec:
      new (&v) vector<Obj>(o.v);
      break;
    }
    type=o.type;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. Sorry for the sloppiness then and thanks. I tried to do that by extracting some meaningful section of the code I was working with, but I guess I should have tried a complete example. For some reason the compiler was complaining about using "incomplete type" and I thought that was the reason.

Comment: No problem. Let's me make a joke: Seneque, *errare humanum est, perseverare diabolicum*. Code are writen by human, and program perseverate. So compilers are devils!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to play with this now, but this might help you:

- the compiler is complaining about usage of incomplete object in your example because it doesn't know the size of Obj at that point.
- try using a raw pointer/unique_ptr/shared_ptr as your vectors value type.